# How use concat in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want get value1, value2, value3... but i have trouble.
why this error?
can't access property "concat", texto1 is undefined
please help me!!
I have the html code:

```
   <div id=items>
   <input type="text" name="cadena1" id="idcadena1" value="valor" />
   <input .....
  </div>

  <div>
    <button name="button" type="button" id="concatenate">concatenar</button>
  </div
    Mi javascript code is the following:
  
    $('#concatenate').click(function () {
      var n = $('#items]').length;
      var texto1 = $('input:first', '#items:first').value;
      var texto2=texto1.concat(n);

    });
```

Comment: with jquery theres no `.value` property - its `.val()`

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery, it's .val() to get/set the value.

```
var texto1 = $('input:first', '#items:first').val();
```